# Why is my Stack Overflow profile avatar image not showing?

Tags: support, profile-picture, avatar

For the last two days, my avatar image has not been showing on my Stack Overflow profile.
Browser: Chrome

[image]

Comment: Have you tried re-uploading the picture?

Comment: Potentially related: [Gravatar is bugging out](/q/421879/15497888)

Comment: Could it be that you are behind e.g. a proxy that is blocking imgur.com?

Comment: @user3170356 yes, I heard of some real-life cases that are due to firewall blocking imgur.